# Three.js - Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a **three.js** project using **parcel** bundler.

Everything is working perfectly in my local system. But when I try to deploy it on **Netlify**, I get the following error:

```js
Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined at app.js:45:16
```

The code in *app.js* at 45 is:

```js
/*41*/  const particlesGeo = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
/*42*/  const particlesMat = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
/*43*/    size: 0.01,
/*44*/    map: loader.load(sparkleTexture),
/*45*/    transparent: true,
/*46*/  });
```

I tried different platforms for the deployment and surge is working perfectly. What could be the problem here on netlify?

---

*Netlify build settings:*

[image: Netlify build settings]

*package.json:*

```json
{
  "name": "particle-system",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "source": "src/index.html", // Added due to parcel error in netlify production
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "gsap": "^3.11.3",
    "parcel": "^2.7.0",
    "three": "^0.145.0"
  }
}
```

*Links:*

- [netlify deployment link](https://particlesystem-3js.netlify.app/)
- [github repository](https://github.com/anushkachauhxn/particle-system-3js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this line in your `app.js` file:

```js
for (i = 0; i < particlesCount * 3; i++) {
```

The runtime error occurs since `i` is not defined. Changed the code to:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < particlesCount * 3; i++) {
```